# Read from console while piping commands in Go

Tags: shell, go, command-line

I need a way to read input from console twice (1 -from `cat` outupt, 2 - user inputs password), like this:
`cat ./test_data/test.txt | app account import`

My current code skips password input:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
raw, err := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
if err != nil {
    return cli.NewExitError(err.Error(), 1)
}

wlt, err := wallet.Deserialize(string(raw))
if err != nil {
    return cli.NewExitError(err.Error(), 1)
}

fmt.Print("Enter password: ")
pass := ""
fmt.Fscanln(reader, &pass)
```

Also tried to read password with `Scanln` - doesn't works.

**Note**: 
`cat` (and piping at all) can't be used with user input, as shell redirects inputs totally.
So the most simple solutions are:

- to pass filename as argument
- redirect manually app account import < ./test.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read file and password separately (and don't show password), try this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "github.com/howeyc/gopass"
)

func main() {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./test_data/test.txt") // just pass the file name
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))

    fmt.Print("Password: ")
    pass, err := gopass.GetPasswd()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(pass))
}
```

and `go get github.com/howeyc/gopass` first.

Comment: Yeap, I already used `terminal.ReadPassword(0)` to hide password.
But I need option to use my app in a shell pipeline

Comment: OK so you need to read from std in , then how do you separate file data  from password? it is one input stream, isn't it? when reading from one stream you need to detect fist data end and second data start, meaning sync header. may be you write a second program like `cat` which  reads from one file and ask password from std in then send output to std out using formatted frame and sync. I hope this helps.

Comment: If you're reading the password from the terminal, it looks like everything is working. Do you still have a problem?

Comment: I forget that while piping, there is no way to interrupt stdin to input password from keyboard. So maybe the option for is just to use filename